# Hbase md5 hash row key confusion

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

Recently I am reserching the hbase row key design, from the Internet I found one method to generate the row key in the md5 hash way, but I cannot understand the theory in the backend. Can someone tell me about this?

```
public byte[] nextId() {
    try {
        currentTime += random.nextInt(1000);
        byte[] lowT = Bytes.copy(Bytes.toBytes(currentTime), 4, 4);
        byte[] lowU = Bytes.copy(Bytes.toBytes(currentId), 4, 4);
        return Bytes.add(MD5Hash.getMD5AsHex(Bytes.add(lowU, lowT)).substring(0, 8).getBytes(),
                Bytes.toBytes(currentId));
    } finally {
        currentId++;
    }
```

Why the author generate the row key in such way? Can anyone explain the code to me line by line please? Thanks in advance!